# Connect 4 class in C#

Tags: c#

I wrote the following class for a connect four game in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConnectFour
{
    class Board
    {
        private string _moves = ""; // stores the moves. This helps in the undo method.
        private const byte RowsCount = 6;
        private const byte ColumnsCount = 7;

        public Piece PlayerTurn { get; private set; } = Piece.Red; // Red plays first.

        public Piece[,] GameBoard { get; private set; } = new Piece[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];

        public void Play(byte columnIndex)
        {
            if (columnIndex >= ColumnsCount) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(columnIndex));
            var column = GetColumn(columnIndex);
            if (column.Count(m => m == Piece.None) == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("This column is already filled.");
            for (var i = column.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (column[i] != Piece.None) continue;
                GameBoard[i, columnIndex] = PlayerTurn;
                _moves += columnIndex.ToString();
                RevertPlayer();
                break;
            }
        }

        public void UndoLastMove()
        {
            if (_moves.Length == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("There is nothing to undo.");
            var tempMoves = _moves.Substring(0, _moves.Length - 1);
            _moves = "";
            GameBoard = new Piece[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];
            PlayerTurn = Piece.Red;
            foreach (var move in tempMoves)
            {
                Play((byte) (move - '0'));
            }
        }

        public Piece CheckForWinner()
        {
            var winningPiece = Piece.None;
            for (byte i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
            {
                winningPiece = HasForInRow(GetColumn(i));
                if (winningPiece != Piece.None) return winningPiece;
            }

            for (byte i = 0; i < RowsCount; i++)
            {
                 winningPiece = HasForInRow(GetRow(i));
                if (winningPiece != Piece.None) return winningPiece;
            }
            // negative slope

            var diagonal1 = new[] {GameBoard[2, 0], GameBoard[3, 1], GameBoard[4, 2], GameBoard[5, 3]};
            var diagonal2 = new[] {GameBoard[1, 0], GameBoard[2, 1], GameBoard[3, 2], GameBoard[4, 3], GameBoard[5, 4]};
            var diagonal3 = new[] {GameBoard[0, 0], GameBoard[1, 1], GameBoard[2, 2], GameBoard[3, 3], GameBoard[4, 4], GameBoard[5, 5]};
            var diagonal4 = new[] {GameBoard[0, 1], GameBoard[1, 2], GameBoard[2, 3], GameBoard[3, 4], GameBoard[4, 5], GameBoard[5, 6]};
            var diagonal5 = new[] {GameBoard[0, 2], GameBoard[1, 3], GameBoard[2, 4], GameBoard[3, 5], GameBoard[4, 6]};
            var diagonal6 = new[] {GameBoard[0, 3], GameBoard[1, 4], GameBoard[2, 5], GameBoard[3, 6]};

            // positive slope
            var diagonal7 = new[] { GameBoard[3, 0], GameBoard[2, 1], GameBoard[1, 2], GameBoard[0, 3] };
            var diagonal8 = new[] { GameBoard[4, 0], GameBoard[3, 1], GameBoard[2, 2], GameBoard[1, 3], GameBoard[0, 4] };
            var diagonal9 = new[] { GameBoard[5, 0], GameBoard[4, 1], GameBoard[3, 2], GameBoard[2, 3], GameBoard[1, 4], GameBoard[0, 5] };
            var diagonal10 = new[] { GameBoard[5, 1], GameBoard[4, 2], GameBoard[3, 3], GameBoard[2, 4], GameBoard[1, 5], GameBoard[0, 6] };
            var diagonal11 = new[] { GameBoard[5, 2], GameBoard[4, 3], GameBoard[3, 4], GameBoard[2, 5], GameBoard[1, 6] };
            var diagonal12 = new[] { GameBoard[5, 3], GameBoard[4, 4], GameBoard[3, 5], GameBoard[2, 6] };

            var diagonals = new[]
            {

                diagonal1,
                diagonal2,
                diagonal3,
                diagonal4,
                diagonal5,
                diagonal6,
                diagonal7,
                diagonal8,
                diagonal9,
                diagonal10,
                diagonal11,
                diagonal12

            };

            foreach (var diagonal in diagonals)
            {
                winningPiece = HasForInRow(diagonal);
                if (winningPiece != Piece.None) return winningPiece;
            }

            return Piece.None;
        }

        private static Piece HasForInRow(Piece[] pieces)
        {
            byte connected = 0;
            var lastPiece = Piece.None;
            foreach (var piece in pieces)
            {
                if (piece == Piece.None)
                {
                    connected = 0;
                    continue;
                }

                if (piece != lastPiece)
                {
                    connected = 1;
                    lastPiece = piece;
                    continue;
                }

                connected++;
                if (connected == 4)
                {
                    return lastPiece;
                }
            }

            return Piece.None;
        }

        private void RevertPlayer()
        {
            PlayerTurn = PlayerTurn == Piece.Red ? Piece.Yellow : Piece.Red;
        }

        private Piece[] GetRow(byte rowIndex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, ColumnsCount).Select(m => GameBoard[rowIndex, m]).ToArray();
        }

        private Piece[] GetColumn(byte columnIndex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, RowsCount).Select(m => GameBoard[m, columnIndex]).ToArray();
        }

    }
}
```

I've read about SOLID and watched videos explaining it. I understand them, but I feel like I can't detect where I'm violating them, and what's the more better way to do things. Please, point me to anything that could be improved, whether it's related to SOLID principles, or any general improvements.

Comment: It might be better if the Piece class was included as well so that we can provide a better review.

Comment: @pacmaninbw, It's just a small enum. `enum Piece { None, Red, Yellow }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not code meets SOLID principles is often most apparent when you want to re-use the code for a similar purpose.  So, given the code you've written, look at it from the perspective that it is not a Connect4 implementation but a XInARowGameEngine (with ConnectFour constraints built-in).  So, in other words, consider what would need to be changed to separate the engine (board management) from the game (ConnectFour) in order to support a similar game like tic-tac-toe.  Doing so will typically reveal a number of areas where SOLID principles could be better applied (in my experience, it always does).

To support re-use would require the ability to resize the game board (3x3), 'CheckForWinner()' might use a parameter to replace the hard coded '4', etc.  But, you can certainly reuse a lot of your existing data manipulations/analysis.  To improve the SOLID-ness of your design, you want to work with abstractions (either interfaces and/or abstract classes).  For example in this case:  `IXInARowGameEngine` and `IConnectFour`.

Psuedo-implemented, perhaps something like:

```
public interface IXInARowGameEngine
{
    int XInARowCriteria { set; get;}
    void GameBoardDimensions(int columns, int rows);
    void Play(byte rowIndex, byte columnIndex);
    void UndoLastMove();
    bool HasXInARow {get;}
}

public class XInARowGameEngine : IXInARowGameEngine
{
    //Implements the interface leveraging your existing code
}

public interface IConnectFour
{
    Piece PlayerOne {set; get;}
    Piece PlayerTwo {set; get;}
    void Play(byte columnIndex);
    void UndoLastMove();
}

public class ConnectFour : IConnectFour
{
    private IXInARowGameEngine _engine; //_engine supports ConnectFour to manipulate the game board
    public ConnectFour(IXInARowGameEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
        _engine.XInARowCriteria = 4;
        _engine.GameBoardDimensions(6, 7);
    }

    public void Play(byte columnIndex)
    {
        //Determine rowIndex
        _engine.Play(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        CheckForWinner();
    }
}
```

So, to get to a Tic-Tac-Toe game...

```
public interface ITicTacToe
{
    Piece PlayerOne {set; get;}
    Piece PlayerTwo {set; get;}
    void Play(byte rowIndex, byte columnIndex);
    void UndoLastMove();
}

public class TicTacToe : ITicTacToe
{
    private IXInARowGameEngine _engine;
    public TicTacToe(IXInARowGameEngine engine)
    {
        _engine = engine;
        _engine.XInARowCriteria = 3;
        _engine.GameBoardDimensions(3, 3);
    }

    public void Play(byte rowIndex, byte columnIndex)
    {
        _engine.Play(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        CheckForWinner();
    }
}
```

So, after all that - even if you never intended to use the `Board` class code for any other similar games - the following improvements have been made:

1. S - Single Responsibility Principal: Now rather than a single `Board` class with all responsibilities, there is are independent engine and the ConnectFour classes each with have their own more narrow responsibility.
2. O - Open/Closed Principle - Exposing the engine only thru `IXInARowGameEngine` opens the `IXInARowGameEngine` behavior for extension, but not modification.
3. L - Liskov substitution principle - For testing, you can now use a stub `IXInARowGameEngine` to test your game independent of using the actual `XInARowGameEngine` class.
4. I - Interface Segregation Principle - You have reduced the implicit Board class public interface to at least two smaller and abstract interfaces with more focused purposes.
5. D - Dependency Inversion - Passing an `IXInARowGameEngine` interface into the constructor of the `ConnectFour` class injects in interface dependency rather than requiring the `ConnectFour` class to instantiate/know-about the `XInARowGameEngine` class.  The `ConnectFour` class' only dependency is the interface definition.

Comment: This is really good. Thanks for that. I've just a small question, what's the benefit from having `ITicTacToe` and `IConnectFour`, why not just the classes ? I understand the benefit of `IXInARowGameEngine` is because we have `_engine` private field in `ConnectFour` and `TicTacToe` classes and that applies that open-closed. But can't get the benefit of `ITicTacToe` and `IConnectFour`.

Comment: If there were any higher level objects that choose and initiate the game(s) the benefits are similar to what `IXInARowGameEngine` provides.  e.g., ITicTacToe and IConnectFour might have a common interface member like `void StartGame();`.  In a small example like this where the games look like the top level object...probably no clear advantage to declaring the interfaces.

Comment: In the `Play` method for `ConnectFour` class, I've to determine `rowIndex` as you have stated by your comment in code. How can I be able to do that if the `IXInARowGameEngine` doesn't expose the array to be public ? Should I add the array to the interface as well ? or there is a better way I'm missing ?

Comment: The thing I don't like about exposing the array to public is that it should only be controlled within the GameEngine only.

Comment: You could have the engine expose a property that returns an array or list of all the occupied (or unoccupied) rows for a given column.  A property like this would let the client game (ConnectFour or Tic-Tac-Toe) calculate the rowIndex without needing access to the entire array.  You are right, exposing the array to public is not a good idea, and would likely break encapsulation.